# Can I remove a hard disk from the boot menu?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, sata

I have two hard disks installed in my PC.  When I boot up my PC and press F8 to reach the boot menu, then I am faced with three options:

```
1) CDROM:PM-TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-322
2) SATA:PS-ST31000524AS
3) IDS:SO Samsung SSD 860 EVO ITB
```

The Samsung SSD contains Windows 10.  The SATA:PS-ST31000524AS is used for file storage.  When I switch on my PC, then sometimes the SATA:PS-ST31000524AS is chosen as the boot device and sometimes the Samsung SSD is chosen as the boot device.  If Samsung is chosen then all is well.  If SATA:PS-ST31000524AS is chosen then two options appear:

```
1) Windows 10 on volume 5
2) Windows 10 on volume 6
```

If I choose either option then I am prompted with a message:

"The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error.  Windows installation cannot proceed.  To install Windows click "OK" to restart the computer, then restart the installation".

For the last three months or so I have always pressed F8 and chosen the correct boot device and never had any problems.  However, over the last few days I have started seeing the blue screen of death two or three times per day and I think it could be due to this.  The BSOD message is: Kernal Security Check Failure.

The reason I think the BSOD could be due to this is because when I unplugged  the SATA:PS-ST31000524AS then I did not see a BSOD all day.

This is my motherboard: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6X58DE/HelpDesk_Download/.  My CPU is: Intel (R) Core i7 950 @ 3.07 GHz. I have the following BIOS: P6X58D-E

Answer (score 0):

You should have to go through any of this.

If you press repeatedly DEL or F2 immediately after power on you should be able to enter the BIOS, and set the default boot device to any device attached to the motherboard.

Independently, your second hard drive could be failing or have bad sectors I don't have enough info for a diagnostic.

You should run a chkdsk /R on the second hard drive.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I specify the drive letter in CHKDSK?

Comment: chkdsk /R d:  (or whatever drive letter it is)

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools that can help remove boot entries.

**MSConfig**

Run MSConfig, position to the Boot tab, click on any unwanted entry and press
"Delete", the OK to terminate.
Be sure not to delete your own boot entry.

**BCDEdit**

- Run Command Prompt as Administrator
- For backup, run `bcdedit /export path`
- Run `bcdedit /v` to list the current boot loaders.
  For EFI boot, use instead `bcdedit /enum firmware`.
- Avoid sections named "Windows Boot Manager", "Windows Boot Loader" or
  "Firmware Boot Manager".
  For EFI, avoid also entries that don't have a "path" item.
- In the other sections, note the long "identifier" string
- To remove, enter the command `bcdedit /delete {identifier-string}`